# How to create triangular matrix that varies with row indices and data?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop, sqrt

I need to calculate some points. First I am going to explain the problem. 
I have a vector of data named X.

```
X=[20 50 100 150 200 300]
```

I need to generate some data and I am using this method:

```
a11=sqrt(1-0/20)-sqrt(1-20/20);
```

That is the result for 20 or X(1).
Then I need to calculate this:

```
a21=sqrt(1-0/50)-sqrt(1-20/50);
a22=sqrt(1-20/50)-sqrt(1-50/50);
```

This is the result for 50 or X(2).

For X(3) i need a31,a32,a33, for X(4) i need a41,a42,a43,a44 ...
Then I need to put that values in matrix in respect to X.

The matrix should look like:

```
20 a11
50 a21 a22
100 a31 a32 a33
150 a41 a42 a43 a44
.
.
.
```

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This problem does not really require two for loops.

Comment: I tried making while loop and nest another while loop in it. If you can solve it without loops fine. I just need the matrix :)

Comment: Nested loops are not necessary. An element can be calculated from it's predecessor. At least if your description is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to add a loop-free solution:

```
X = [20 50 100 150 200 300];
X2 = [0 X];
outmat = [X.', tril(-diff(sqrt(1-(1./X).'*X2),1,2))];
```

The non-trivial part of the output matrix works like this: it first computes the `sqrt(1-X(k)/X(l))` kinds of values in a matrix, essentially creating the matrix as a dyadic product of `X` and `X2` (the latter is `X` extended with a leading `0` element). Then, we compute the `diff` of this matrix along its second dimension: be careful that the second input parameter of `diff` gives the *order* of the numerical derivative. Then we cut out the lower-triangular part with `tril`.

Comment: Thank you. Answer is compact and loop free. :)

Comment: @silent_bob if the loops are no hard requirement, you might want to edit your question title.

Comment: @Adriaan I don't think it is, but this seems the most elegant in this case (I might be biased though:P)

Comment: Well i didnt know that it can be done without loops. But now as we can see there are a couple of elegant solutions. I edited the question, but the idea is the same. It can be done using loops or on this way.

Answer (score 4):

```
X = [20 50 100 150 200 300];
N = length(X);
result = zeros(N, N);

for row = 1:N
    % Calculate current line
    result(row, 1) = sqrt( 1 - 0/X(row) ) - sqrt( 1 - X(1)/X(row) );
    for col = 2:row
        result(row, col) = sqrt( 1 - X(col-1)/X(row) ) - sqrt( 1 - X(col)/X(row) );
    end
end

% Prepend with X as a row vector
result = [ X.', result ];
```

Comment: You hard-coded the number `50` in it, but I think the OP wants to increase that through `X` as well

Comment: Good point, I missed that, thanks. This might require nested loops now. :D

Comment: I fixed my solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your calculation can be done without loops. As there is no recursive calculation. Following will do the trick.

```
B = sqrt(tril(1-bsxfun(@rdivide,[0 X],X'),1));
A = [X' -diff(B,1,2)];
```

`bsxfun` will create all the fractions you have inside your roots. As you only want to calculate the differences of the lower triangular matrix I use `tril(FUN,1)` to set the rest to zero. The second line will calulate the differences of your matrix in the second dimension. Just append `X'`and you have the desired matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as well:

```
% clear all ; clc; %// not generally appreciated
X = [0 20 50 100 150 200 300];
n = length(X)-1;
result = tril(ones(n));
for i = 1:(n-1)
   X_max = X(i+1);    
   for j=1:i
      result(i,j) = result(i,j) .* sqrt(1 - X(j)/X_max) - sqrt(1 - X(j+1)/X_max);
   end    
end
```

Answer (score -4):

First thing, use a vector of cell so you can store a matrix with different dimension in each cell (the horizontal vectors of different length).

And then, just a double loop as:

```
for i = 1:length(X)
  for j = 1:i
     %Your computation
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it's OK to have a zero-padded matrix. Cells should be avoided when possible:)

Comment: Also, your answer doesn't answer the question at all, so I'm downvoting.